# Better Approach of writing Inner Join?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

**Which approach should I use  ?**

This

```
Select * from table1,table2 where table1.id=table2.id;
```

or

```
Select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id;
```

***Note :*** Id is foriegn Key .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most modern RMDBS both would yield the same execution plan but
the second one is the reccommended form since it makes clear what are the `join` conditions right after you declare said `join`

Comment: Also, the explicit join syntax is part of ANSI standard 1992.

Comment: also the second states "inner" which makes it clearer to the reader

Answer (score 0):

If your query gets big as they do, the second style is usually regarded as easier to read and comprehend as the JOIN and the WHERE parts of the query are separated.

```
Select * from table1 
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id=table2.id
INNER JOIN table3 on table1.id=table3.id
WHERE table2.something = 1
```

Indeed both styles should have the same execution pan under the hood.